# Apache Rewrite URL in .htaccess File: Remove Subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, rule

How do you remove a folder from the URL using a rewrite rule from the .htaccess file?

Instead of:

```
http://www.example.com/city/houston/
```

Or:

```
http://www.example.com/city/chicago/
```

The URL would display as:

```
http://www.example.com/houston/
```

Or

```
http://www.example.com/chicago/
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Root/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /city/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: It didn't work. Perhaps because it's a WordPress site?